# Sorting left join results on large open schema tables

Tags: mysql

I am designing an open schema database with the following table definitions

```
mysql> desc orders;
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID    | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| json  | text    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> desc ordersnames;
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(330) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

with an index on name

```
mysql> desc orderskeys;
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID        | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| reference | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| nameref   | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| value     | varchar(330) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

with indices on:

reference,nameref,value

nameref,value

reference

All json fields (1 dimension only) have entry in the orderskeys table per existing field, whereby nameref is a reference to the field name as defined in ordersname.

I would typically query like this:

```
SELECT
    orderskeysdeliveryPostcode.value deliveryPostcode,
    orders.ID,
    orderskeysCN.value CN
FROM
    orders
JOIN ordersnames as ordersnamesCN   
    on ordersnamesCN.name = 'CN'
JOIN  orderskeys as orderskeysCN
    on orderskeysCN.nameref = ordersnamesCN.ID
    and orderskeysCN.reference = orders.ID
    and orderskeysCN.value = '10094'
JOIN ordersnames as ordersnamesdeliveryPostcode
    on ordersnamesdeliveryPostcode.name = 'deliveryPostcode'
JOIN orderskeys as orderskeysdeliveryPostcode
    on orderskeysdeliveryPostcode.nameref = ordersnamesdeliveryPostcode.ID
    and orderskeysdeliveryPostcode.reference = orders.ID
order by deliveryPostcode
limit 0,1000
```

yielding a result set like this

```
 +------------------+--------+-------+
 | deliveryPostcode | ID     | CN    |
 +------------------+--------+-------+
 | NULL             | 251018 | 10094 |
 | NULL             | 157153 | 10094 |
 | NULL             |  95419 | 10094 |
 | B-5030           | 172944 | 10094 |
 +------------------+--------+-------+
```

-> lightning fast even with 400k + orders records

However, not all record do contain all fields, so the above query will not yield the records that do not have a 'deliveryPostcode field', so I have to query like this

```
SELECT
    orderskeysdeliveryPostcode.value deliveryPostcode,
    orders.ID,
    orderskeysCN.value CN
FROM
    orders
JOIN ordersnames as ordersnamesCN   
    on ordersnamesCN.name = 'CN'
JOIN  orderskeys as orderskeysCN
    on orderskeysCN.nameref = ordersnamesCN.ID
    and orderskeysCN.reference = orders.ID
    and orderskeysCN.value = '10094'
JOIN ordersnames as ordersnamesdeliveryPostcode
    on ordersnamesdeliveryPostcode.name = 'deliveryPostcode'
LEFT JOIN orderskeys as orderskeysdeliveryPostcode
    on orderskeysdeliveryPostcode.nameref =   ordersnamesdeliveryPostcode.ID
    and orderskeysdeliveryPostcode.reference = orders.ID
limit 0,1000
```

-> equally fast, but as soon as I add an ORDER BY clause on the key value from a left joined table, mysql wants to do the sorting externally (temporary, filesort) instead of using an existing index.

```
SELECT
    orderskeysdeliveryPostcode.value deliveryPostcode,
    orders.ID,
    orderskeysCN.value CN
FROM
    orders
JOIN ordersnames as ordersnamesCN   
    on ordersnamesCN.name = 'CN'
JOIN  orderskeys as orderskeysCN
    on orderskeysCN.nameref = ordersnamesCN.ID
    and orderskeysCN.reference = orders.ID
    and orderskeysCN.value = '10094'
JOIN ordersnames as ordersnamesdeliveryPostcode
    on ordersnamesdeliveryPostcode.name = 'deliveryPostcode'
LEFT JOIN orderskeys as orderskeysdeliveryPostcode
    on orderskeysdeliveryPostcode.nameref =   ordersnamesdeliveryPostcode.ID
    and orderskeysdeliveryPostcode.reference = orders.ID
ORDER BY deliveryPostCode
limit 0,1000
```

-> very slow ...

In fact the sorting operation itself is not much different , as all NULL values for column deliveryPostcode would be at the beginning (ASC) or the end (DESC) while the rest of the dataset would have the same order as with JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN.

How can I query (and order) such tables efficiently? Do I need different relations or indices ?

Much obliged ...

Comment: so, you didn't post the query with problem? only 2 good ones?

Comment: ammended the post withe query with ORDER BY (thought it was clear)

Comment: no it is not clear for me. your first query has `order by` and you wrote **lightning fast even with 400k + orders records** so you have no problem with this order by. so I have no idea with which one you have ?

Comment: The difference to the first query is the LEFT JOIN on orderskeys. Note that the query remains really fast as long as the order by is done on JOINed tables or on LEFT JOINed tables without ordering

Comment: try `ORDER BY orderskeysdeliveryPostcode.value`

Comment: Tried that, no change -> explain says usign temporary, filesort

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72584/discussion-between-freud-chicken-and-alex).

Comment: did you check my answer?

Comment: Checked your answer, does not work

Comment: what exactly does not work?

Answer (score 1):

With INNER JOINs, to reduce the number of lookups, MySQL is going to start with the table with the fewest rows (see the EXPLAIN result to see which table MySQL starts with).

If you order by anything other than a column in that first table, or there is no index to satisfy the ORDER BY clause on that first table, MySQL is going to have to do a filesort.

The use of a temporary table is much more likely when text columns are involved, and not just an in-memory temporary table, but a dreadful on-disk temporary table.

Use `STRAIGHT_JOIN` to force the order that MySQL performs inner joins.

Comment: This comes much closer to the research I have doe so far ;) I have experimented with straight_join in this context (to no much avail). The problem however seems to be that the set I do want to order is not in an indexed table entirely but contains NULL value for rows joined where no correspondent exists. As said in the post, this is however not relevant for the sorting order as such as al NULL value would be at the begin or end of the ordered dataset

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure what logic do you have in some parts of your query.

I think it still can be optimized.

But just to resolve the issue you have, try just switch it to `RIGHT JOIN` for now:

```
 SELECT 
  orderskeysdeliveryPostcode.value deliveryPostcode,
  o.id,
  o.CN
FROM orderskeys as orderskeysdeliveryPostcode
INNER JOIN ordersnames as ord_n
    on ord_n.id = orderskeysdeliveryPostcode.nameref
      AND ord_n.name = 'deliveryPostcode'
RIGHT JOIN (
SELECT
    orders.ID,
    orderskeysCN.CN
FROM
    orders
LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT 
     orderskeys.value as CN,
     orderskeys.reference
   FROM 
    orderskeys 
   INNER JOIN ordersnames as ordersnamesCN   
   ON ordersnamesCN.id = orderskeys.nameref
      AND ordersnamesCN.name = 'CN'
   WHERE orderskeys.value = '12209'
  ) as orderskeysCN
 ON
  orderskeysCN.reference = orders.ID
limit 0,1000
) as o
on 
  orderskeysdeliveryPostcode.reference = o.ID
ORDER BY deliveryPostCode;
```

and here is [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1ee12/29) we can play with. Just need you to add data inserts there.

Comment: This yields an error because of the first order by (after the from), as dataset ordered by order by cannot be unioned or joined further. Even removing that line does not work as it does not implement the logic of the query at all. To avoid misunderstandings , I added a sample output of what a resultset for these queries looks like to the original post.

Comment: so you don't want to get NULLs? then it is not left or right joins - it is INNER. try updated answer

Comment: @FreudChicken and reading the data you've placed in your post - I can't understand how your record can hold `NULL` when `CN` field is not empty?

Comment: The nulls are confusing I admit. I want to get all records , if the contain data for deliveryPostcode or not. I easily do that by means of the query with the left join on orderskeysdeliveryPostcode. However, any order by on the resulting recordset refuses to use the index on orderskeys for ordering, but creates a temp table, which takes ages to sort.

Comment: I understood the problem you have. that is why I am trying to switch the query from LEFT to RIGHT. it must return the same result, just the order of query - subquery is changed. and mysql server should use your index

Comment: @FreudChicken can you set up sql fiddle with some data? to help me debug?

Comment: the NULLS are some stray records in orderskeys containing NULL for the value field. They are not representative, the example is to show the format of the result set. Most records however do not have an entry in orderskeys, if deliveryPostcode is empty

Comment: so I changed back RIGHT join as soon as nulls are correct values. can you set up the sqlfiddle with some data?

Comment: Note that LIMIT *without* ORDER BY is pretty much meaningless.

Comment: @Strawberry no, in this particular case it has sense. so we can get 500 items with NULL (not ordered) and the rest ordered by postcode. But we have a lot of fun if there is 1000 items with NULL ;-)

Comment: @FreudChicken ohh finally, I found typo in my query.check update please, there is no `ORDER BY`  before `RIGHT JOIN`

Comment: @Alex, your query does not at all correspond to the logic of this schema

Comment: does it return any records?

Comment: @FreudChicken check last update. my query based on sqlfiddle you provided.

Comment: There's a fiddle? Is it secret?